# Windows form Chart label modification

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Am creating an windows form application which uses chart.I want to modify the chart

1. How to edit the chart area back ground color (white color in in screen shot)
2. How to apply different color to each bar.
3. How to format the Y axis label(need to align the file extension to left end and integer value to right end)

This is my current screen shot

[image]

Need to update my screen like this

[image]

Is it possible to align label like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

[image]

To style the `Chart` you use this:

```
// prepare:
chart1.Series.Clear();
Series S1 = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

// style type, font, color, axes
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
CA.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
chart1.BackColor = CA.BackColor;
Font f = new Font("Consolas", 10f);
CA.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = f;

S1.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
CA.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
CA.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
CA.AxisX.LineColor = Color.Transparent;

CA.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
CA.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
CA.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
```

To color individual `DataPoints` you must set their `Color`:

```
S1.Points[0].Color = Color.YellowGreen;
S1.Points[1].Color = Color.YellowGreen;
```

To create the [formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) labels you can create the strings and use them as (pseudo) X-Values when adding the points:

```
string label = string.Format("{0,-11}{1, 7:0.0}%{2,8:##0.0}GB  ",
                t.Item1, t.Item2 * 100d / total, t.Item2) + "\u2001\u2001";
int idx = S1.Points.AddXY(label, t.Item2);
```

Here I use a `Tuple<string, int>` to hold my data. You will need to adapt this to your data source. Note how I calculate the percentage from a total.

Here is the full code I used for my example data:

```
List<Tuple<string, double>> data = new List<Tuple<string, double>>()
{
    new Tuple<string, double>( "0-1 months", 4 ),
    new Tuple<string, double>( "2-3 months", 14 ),
    new Tuple<string, double>( "4-11 months", 44 ),
    new Tuple<string, double>( "1-2 years", 23 ),
    new Tuple<string, double>( "3-5 years", 3 ),
    new Tuple<string, double>( "> 5 years", 100 ),

};

double total = data.Sum(x => x.Item2);

foreach (Tuple<string, double> t in data)
{
    string label = string.Format("{0,-11}{1, 7:0.0}%{2,8:##0.0}GB",
                   t.Item1, t.Item2 * 100d / total, t.Item2) + "\u2001\u2001";
    int i = S1.Points.AddXY(label, t.Item2);
    S1.Points[i].Font = f;
}
```

Notes:

- To get internal string alignment you need to use a **monospaced** font like `Consolas`.
- Also note that you **can't** use different fonts or styles inside one label.
- I add two [m-space characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) to create a distance between labels and the plotarea. (Normal spaces would not display!).

**Update:**

The second chart image shows a `SeriesChartType.Column`. To insert new lines all you need to do is insert a `\n` character and make sure there is enough room.

The tricky part is have one line in a different color. This is not possible with Labels.

Instead you need to add two `CustomLabels` per datapoint: The fist one shows the e.g. black lines. The second one can have a different `ForeColor` and need to have as many `\n` at the beginning as the first one has lines.

Note that `CustomLabels` sit in the middle between two positions. So I have now added the `DataPoints` with real numbers, starting with 0, as their X-Values and then position the `CustomLabels` halfway between..

[image]

```
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    Series S1 = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
    S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    chart1.Legends.Clear();

    CA.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    chart1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    Font f = new Font("Consolas", 9f);

    CA.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = f;

    S1.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.LeftRight;
    CA.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    CA.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    CA.AxisX.LineColor = Color.Transparent;

    CA.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
    CA.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    CA.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;

    CA.Position.X = 0f;

    List<Tuple<string, double>> data = new List<Tuple<string, double>>()
    {
        new Tuple<string, double>( "0-1 months", 4 ),
        new Tuple<string, double>( "2-3 months", 14 ),
        new Tuple<string, double>( "4-11 months", 44 ),
        new Tuple<string, double>( "1-2 years", 23 ),
        new Tuple<string, double>( "3-5 years", 3 ),
        new Tuple<string, double>( "> 5 years", 100 ),

    };

    double total = data.Sum(x => x.Item2);

    foreach (Tuple<string, double> t in data)
    {
        string label1 = string.Format("{0}\n{1:0.0}%", t.Item1, t.Item2 * 100d / total);
        string label2 = string.Format("\n\n{0:##0.0}GB", t.Item2);
        int i = S1.Points.AddXY(S1.Points.Count, t.Item2);
        S1.Points[i].Font = f;

        DataPoint dp = S1.Points[i];
        int v = (int)dp.YValues[0];
        CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
        cl.Text = label1;
        cl.FromPosition = i - 0.5f;
        cl.ToPosition = i + 0.5f;

        CustomLabel cl2 = new CustomLabel();
        cl2.Text = label2;
        cl2.FromPosition = i -0.5f;
        cl2.ToPosition = i + 0.5f;

        cl2.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        CA.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
        CA.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(cl2);

    }
    S1.Points[0].Color = Color.YellowGreen;
    S1.Points[1].Color = Color.YellowGreen;
```

Comment: I added one more screen shot,could you please help me to format the label like that..

Comment: I have added a few hints on how you can do something like the 2nd image.

Comment: Thanks for the update.Could please provide a sample code for customLabels