# Windows Forms Chart set fixed mixed labels

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, charts, axis-labels

I would like to fix my labels on my x or y axis, so they are always static. I also want to mix the labelling with numbers and strings like in shown picture. Furthermore the y axis starting with -1, how can I always start with 0?

[image]

Comment: Use CustomLabels and set the Minimum on the Y-Axis!

Comment: @TaW I tried to set them up in the CustomLabels Properties Editor in Visual Studio, but they are not shown. The lables of the y-axis just disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting [`CustomLabels`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.customlabel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is tricky as their [`FromPositions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.customlabel.fromposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`ToPositions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.customlabel.toposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) need to be set correctly or else they won't show at the right positions!

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893852/windows-form-chart-label-modification/31895616?s=1|0.4010#31895616) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432342/different-label-types-on-one-axis-in-chart/32444146?s=2|0.3914#32444146) for more examples!

Here is one for your question, as I read it:

```
CA.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
CA.AxisY.Maximum = 4;
CA.AxisY.Interval = 1;

int old = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel(i - 0.5d, i + 0.5d, 
                i < old ? i + "" : i == old ? "old" : "too old", 0, LabelMarkStyle.None);
    CA.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
}
```

[image]

The [`Minimum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`Maximum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) values shown can be set for all axes separately. With `CustomLabels` we often need to enforce the [`Interval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ..

Using the same [setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556748/unproportional-bubble-chart-with-the-size-paramater-in-c-sharp-visual-studio/33557399#33557399) code as in your other question..