# WinForms Chart control - Show labels between ticks

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

By default the [WinForms Chart control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx) shows labels centrally below the ticks.

Is there any way to change that so that the labels are shown between the ticks instead, as per this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do this would be to use custom labels.  That means taking over the job of adding the labels from the control and doing it manually yourself, which may or may not be suitable in your case.

The ["Labeling Axes Using Custom Labels" section of the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628.aspx) describes this in more detail:

> Use custom labels to provide custom text for axes. Custom labels are
>   implemented using the CustomLabels collection property. If you use
>   custom labels, the chart area does not display axis labels from data
>   points.
>
> When using CustomLabel objects, you must set the ToPosition and
>   FromPosition properties of each CustomLabel object, and these
>   properties must specify the width of the label's text area. Do not
>   assign the same value to both of these properties because they
>   represent a range. To position a custom label directly beneath a data
>   point and its associated tick mark, set the FromPosition property to
>   the value of that data point's axis minus half of the tick mark
>   interval, and set the ToPosition property to the value of that data
>   point's axis plus half of the tick mark interval. For example, if an
>   axis has an interval of 1 (1, 2, 3,…), and you want to use a custom
>   label at X=2, then set the ToPosition and FromPosition properties to
>   1.5 and 2.5, respectively.
>
> The RowIndex property specifies on which row the custom label is
>   displayed. If a custom label is used in the first label row, the chart
>   area does not display any labels from the axis scale. The only labels
>   permitted in the second row and beyond are custom labels.

In your case you don't want the labels to be directly below the tick mark, so in the example in the quoted text above you'd set your position ToPosition to 2 and your FromPosition to 3.

Looking at your specific graph, if the x-axis values are DateTimes, you'll need to check if the To/From Positions will work with DateTimes.  If not, you may need to convert the values to serial numbers (you could use e.g. [`DateTime.ToOADate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this) before using them for the x-axis.  That won't effect what's displayed as you will be replacing those labels with your own ones anyway, which you can then format as you wish.

Comment: _in the example above you'd set your position ToPosition to 2 and your FromPosition to 3._ The chart shown at least looks as if the datatype is datetime. if it is your code won't work.

Comment: @TaW Sorry, perhaps that was confusingly worded, my code referred to how you would adapt the example in the quoted text, not the OP's original image.  I've updated my response to make that clearer and added the outline of what's needed in case the x-axis values are dates.

Comment: Well that is at least a little closer. The actual values are always double though and either already contain the converted ToOADate numbers or 0 (if the values were added as strings.) So, yes one can use those numbers to determine the to- and fromValues but it will be tedious. I still prefer my solution; but now I can retract my downvote :-)

Answer (score -1):

The regular Labels will always show with the DataPoints. But you can show the tick marks between.

Depending on the datatype and `Interval` you can set an `MajorTickMark.IntervalOffset`:

[image]
[image]

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.IntervalOffset =
                     chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval / 2f;
```

Note: For this to work you need to **set** the `Interval`. By default it is set to `0.0`, so you need to set it to some other value! Most of the tome a value of `1` will be fine.

The harder altenative would be to use  `CustomLabels` for that.. Much more work for the same result. Not really recommended. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556991/windows-forms-chart-set-fixed-mixed-labels/33559004?s=2|0.1717#33559004)

Comment: I think he wants to reposition the labels, not the tick marks.

Comment: Maybe, but as I wrote, this is not possible. He will have to use `CustomLabels` for that..