# Winforms - How to get label in between of the x-axis datapoints

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, charts

System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

BarCharts - Current:

[image]

Bar Charts - Required:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Is it possible for me to get the label in between the x axis ticks?

Thanks!

Comment: Which chart class/framework are you using?

Comment: Hi there, I'm using this:
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Comment: Hi Jenny. It is a good practice on this site to edit your original question in order to add new details instead of using comments, as comments might easily be overlooked.

Comment: Noted, updated as per advice :)

Comment: Not really. The `DataPoints` are centered at their values and the `Labels` sit at the center. For a given `Axis ax` you can set the ax.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset`  but that is not going to be what you want. - And:  These are `Columns` (not `Bars` btw) not Rectangles aka `Areas`. You can try increasing their Width to make the gap go away but it is tricky once the number of DataPoints changes. Maybe switching to another ChartType (Area) altogether is better..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

[WinForms Chart control - Show labels between ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148734/winforms-chart-control-show-labels-between-ticks)

[How to give custom labels to x axis of chart control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691679/how-to-give-custom-labels-to-x-axis-of-chart-control)

1) Change the AxisX tick position.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.IntervalOffset =
                        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval / 2f;
```

2) Set up the Custom Label

```
int startOffset = 0;
int endOffset = 1;

for (int i = earliestHour; i <= latestHour; i++)
{
   CustomLabel label_chart = new CustomLabel(startOffset, endOffset, xAxis_Label,0, LabelMarkStyle.None);                       
   chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(label_chart);
   startOffset+=1;
   endOffset+=1;
}
```

And... you get this!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMbSB.jpg)

Comment: Well, using CustomLabels you can show any kind of info, even as wrong and misleading as you seem to want it..